# APNs Auth Key cannot be download

Tags: xcode, key, apple-push-notifications, apple-developer

My team created max limit for APNs Auth Key in developer portal
I cannot download any of them as the downlod button is dimmed !

Anyone has any idea why is that? and how can i use it without expiring any of them and create a new one ?

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: I've been looking everwhere but there seems to be no solution as of the moment.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same issue here. Is there any option to at-least download the existing .p8 file?

Comment: Had the same, however the keys can be downloaded only once, and we had most likely done that and forgotten. So we deleted the key, recreated and could then download. At creation there is also an option to defer download and click "Done", in which case the disabled download option on the view you pasted would presumably be active for one download.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

APNs Auth Key `.p8` **CAN ONLY BE DOWNLOADED ONCE** from Apple's developer portal, so only download it when you are ready to use and store securely!

If you need the `p.8` file and you have lost it, you have to revoke the existing one and create a new one.

Since Apple allows only two such files to exist at any time on the account, it is recommended that all apps on the account share the same APNs Key. This works as the key is per account and not per app.

The remaining slot ideally should be kept free and only used when for some reason the existing key should be revoked. Then a new key is added on the account and the old one kept alive until all apps in the account update to the new key.

Comment: What happens when you revoke a key? Does it affect the apps that uses it?

Comment: @suatkorkmaz when you revoke it, of course it will affect the apps that are using it. You can create new ones and replace